# Angled div with content

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have a requirement to layout a site with angled div elements that meet the following requirements:

1. Height of the sections must be ~400 px when showing topics side by side and ~800px when the columns collapse vertically. Ideally this would auto-adjust to the enclosed content.
2. It must angle downwards at a **locked** 7 degrees
3. Full Width of the screen
4. Must be able to contain an image background instead of just a solid color

**Example:**

[image: Example product]

**Code I have so far:**

```css
.centeredContent{    
    transform: rotate(7deg) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg) translateY(-50%); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg) translateY(-50%);
    top:46%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(120,0,0,.0)
 }

.rotateBack {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    background-color:rgba(0,120,0,.0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="div1" style="background-color:rgba(77,77,77,.2); position:relative;overflow:hidden;">  
    <div id="content1" class="centeredContent">
        <div class="row" >
           
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 rotateBack">
                <h2 style="color:#8aada8">topic 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem...</p>
                <button style="width:185px;height:52px;">Learn More</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-4 rotateBack">
                <h2 style="color:#8aada8">topic 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ...</p>
                <button style="width:185px;height:52px;">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,100,.0);overflow:hidden">
        <svg width="100%" id="svg1" style="margin:0;padding:0px;" viewBox="0 0 1590 600">
            <polygon id="polygon1" points="0,0 0,400 1590,600 1590,200" style="fill:#525252;stroke:#525252;stroke-width:0" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that my gray bar doesn't size correctly to my content. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

In your "centeredContent" class add attribute "width:100%", that should solve the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the gray bar to resize based on the size of your content I wouldn't use SVG. Here I've removed the SVG and I've wrapped the content in a div which is rotated the exact same way you had done previously.

The width is set to 120% so that the edges of the div are masked by it's container. The div now adapts to the height of the containing content and will grow larger when the content stacks.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,100,.0)
}

.centeredContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #525252;
  width: 120%;
  padding: 40px 150px;
}

.rotateBack {
  transform: rotate(-7deg) translateY(-10%);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="box">

  <div id="content1" class="centeredContent">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 rotateBack">
        <h2 style="color:#8aada8">topic 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem...</p>
        <button style="width:185px;height:52px;">Learn More</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-4 rotateBack">
        <h2 style="color:#8aada8">topic 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ...</p>
        <button style="width:185px;height:52px;">Learn More</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```